# Group by an entire array as a record in MongoDB and aggregation Frameword

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with this format bellow, containing some arrays (`document`) maybe duplicated so I have to perform an aggregation grouping by the array to avoid duplication and have the correspondant `total` of each unique array.

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("59ce3bb32708c95ee2168e2f"),
    "document" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "b"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c"
        }
    ],

        "total" :5    ]

},

{"_id" : ObjectId("59ce3bb32708c95ee2168e2f"),
    "document" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "b"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c"
        }
    ],

        "total" :4    ]

},
{"_id" : ObjectId("59ce3bb32708c95ee2168e2f"),
    "document" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "b"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c"
        }
    ],

        "total" :2    ]

}
```

I have to group by the array document1 and sum the `total` by unique array values to get the result as :

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("59ce3bb32708c95ee2168e2f"),
    "document" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "a"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "b"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c"
        }
    ],

        "total" :9    ]

},
{"_id" : ObjectId("59ce3bb32708c95ee2168e2f"),
    "document" : [ 
        {
            "value" : "b"
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "c"
        }
    ],

        "total" :2    ]
}
```

if I group by array `$document` I can't get as an `_id` an array in the `outOperation`, so the purpose is to store the result in the collection.

Comment: Add a project operation before out stage. Something like `{$project:{_id:0, document:"$_id", total:1}}`. This will output a new id when you save into collection.

Comment: Thank you very much Veeram, it's working now